# How can I call an angular.factory within an angular.value or an angular.constant?

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('myGlobals', function ($http) {
    function getCountries() {
        var countries = [];
        $http.get('http://whatever/v1/countries').then(function (response) {
            countries = response.data;
        });
        return countries;
    }

    return {
        getCountries: getCountries
    }
});
```

**Constant defined in an angular.module**

```
.constant ('SomeSchema', {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        host: {type: 'string', title: 'Host'},
        ip: {type: 'string', title: 'IP'},
        country: {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'Country',
            enum: getCountries
        },
        status: {type: 'boolean', title: 'Status'}
    },
    required : [
        "host","ip","country","status"
    ]
})
```

What should I do, so that I can use e.g. getCountries in the example above? (yes it is a constant, please ignore this issue..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is the shorthand for `provider` with [predefined `$get` function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/auto/injector.js#L699), it can't be injected with dependencies. `factory` is the shorthand also, and it can be injected with dependencies. Use

```
.factory('SomeSchema', function (myGlobals) {
    return { ... };
})
```

> yes it is a constant, please ignore this issue..

It can't be ignored, because the distinctive feature of constants is that they can be used in config blocks, where `myGlobals` factory isn't available yet.